# Vue.js v-for item, bind attribute to current index / key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<li v-for="(value, key) in {facebook: [data], twitter: [data]}">
    <i class="icon" :class="key"></i>
    ....
</li>
```

Error:  `[Vue warn]: Trying to access non-existent property "key" while rendering.`

How can I bind `key` in attributes of `li`'s children? It only works in `li` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works as expected for me. If you inspect the items in the snippet below, you'll see the class is assigned.

```js
new Vue({el: 'body'});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<li v-for="(key, value) in {facebook: ['data'], twitter: ['data']}">
  <i class="icon" :class="key">{{key}}</i>
</li>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it does. Thanks. It was my HTML structure.